# mysql querying data that INSIDE two date's column

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have a table with structure:

```
events
----------
id
name
start_date
end_date
```

and i need to build a calendar preview for this events.
so user can choose the date range that they want to show.

Let's say that we have some data like this :

```
1 | event A | 01-02-2022 | 10-02-2022
```

So there is a request with two parameters, from and to parameter so that user can choose what dates that they want to show on calendar (frontend) and it will be requested to backend

There are three cases:

1. user choose from `01-02-2022` to `28-02-2022` (monthly)
2. user choose from `06-02-2022` to `12-02-2022` (weekly)
3. user choose from `20-01-2022` to `03-02-2022` (custom)

I want these three cases will show event with id 1

The thing is, if I use conventional using `between` query filter, it will generate a query like this:

```
1. select * from events where start_date between '01-02-2022' and '28-02-2022'
2. select * from events where start_date between '06-02-2022' and '12-02-2022'
3. select * from events where start_date between '20-01-2022' and '03-02-2022'
```

For the first case, it will show event with id 1 because `start_date` satisfied `between` query.

But for the second and third case, its not because `start_date` is not satisfied `between` query.

What I want is that for second and third case, my query would return the event with id 1 too because between `06-02-2022` to `12-02-2022` and `20-01-2022` to `03-02-2022` has some dates that within the event 1 start and end range

Could anyone give me an example query that will satisfy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not getting the last two cases correct because you are not checking for the `end_date`.

Try including the `end_date` as well in your condition:

```sql
select * from events 
where (start_date between '01-02-2022' and '28-02-2022') or (end_date between '01-02-2022' and '28-02-2022')
```

Comment: Eh haha how come I didn't realize this logic hahaha. Thankyou kRiz, its really solved my issue